# Workflow Lookup to multiple values

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

Assume a three lists as below:

1. User (Name)
2. Process (Title, Members)

How can we lookup a person where the person is one of the process members?

In short, I don't know how to lookup over an array or list of values in a workflow.

Comment: What I did: Custom Activity + CAML